# 405 (Method Not Allowed) using Angular httpClient POST

Tags: .net, angular, http, post

This is the method I use in Angular for making the POST request:

```
newMessage(m: Message) {
  this.http
    .post<any>('http://localhost:55820/api/message', m)
    .subscribe(res => (console.log(res)));
}
```

On the server side with asp.net WebApi 2, I receive the request like this:

```
[Route("api/message")]
[HttpPost]
public IHttpActionResult Create(Message message)
{
    return Ok("Ok");
}
```

With `PostMan` the request works fine but using Angular I get an `OPTIONS` request with a 405 state code instead of the POST request. Am I missing something? Thanks!

Comment: The `OPTIONS` is a [CORS Preflight request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Preflight_request). You'll need to make sure that CORS is configured on the server. Postman won't send a Preflight request because it uses a normal POST request, unfortunately AJAX requests are different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I didn't configure CORS on the server side. As I'm using .net WebApi 2 for the backend, the only steps I had to follow for solving were the following:

1. Install CORS (With Nuget package manager)

> Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Cors

2. Add this line to WebApiConfig.cs

> config.EnableCors();

3. Add this line to the controller before the class declaration

> [EnableCors(origins: "http://localhost:4200", headers:
>   "*", methods: "*")]

In my case localhost:4200 is my frontend side address. For more information visit the full tutorial: https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/aspnet/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api

Answer (score 0):

Try with `[FromBody]`

```
 public IHttpActionResult Create([FromBody] Message message)
```

As For complex types (your own object, for example: Message), Web API tries to read the value from the body of the HTTP request.

Also make sure you handle **CORS** in your backend.